# Cмысл поговорки «Что бы русские ни делали, всё автомат Калашникова получается»

Tags: перевод, выражения

Как наиболее доступным образом (по возможности, используя аналогичные английские обороты) объяснить изучающим русский язык смысл поговорки 
«Что бы русские ни делали, всё автомат Калашникова получается» ?

<sup><sup>P.S.: Ближайшая по посылу находка из мира животных — «Что можно ждать от свиньи кроме хрюканья» (What can you expect from a hog but a grunt). Однако, из-за негативных коннотаций этот вариант сложно назвать адекватным. Ну и вроде как автомат калашникова наша гордость, просто мы склонны делать вот таким образом.</sup></sup>

Comment: This is an interesting question, and I would recommend to restore it.

Comment: It is an interesting question, it's just not fit for this site. Translate it to English, with all the sufficient context explanations and I'll migrate it to English.SE